# react-bootstrap - How to use server side rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-rails, server-side-rendering

I'm using Rails with react-rails gem. Server side works perfect, but recently I added react-bootstrap to the project.

All good, except the fact that react-server references twice the react script, which causes inconsistencies with the react-bootstrap

Let me show you. Inside my application.js I reference the following:

```
..
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require react_bootstrap
//= require utils
//= require components
..
```

Inside components

```
..
//= require react-server
//= require stuff
..
```

I render component using react_component, with prerender: true. It works great, but if you use, let's say, Input (from React-bootstrap) then it complains about addToRef error, which is caused by multiple react referencing

If I remove react/react_ujs then I no longer have React on the client. If I remove react-server then I no longer have react on server. But if I remove react-server then React-bootstrap no longer complains about multiple references

Is there are way to use react server side together with React-bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

`react-server` and `react` *both* have full copies of `React`!  The only difference is that `react-server` *also* includes `ReactDOMServer`.

I think for `components.js` you could have:

```
//= require react-server 
//= require stuff
```

Then in `application.js`

```
//= require components 
//= require react_ujs
```

I use a similar arrangement because i need `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` in the browser.